# what bluetooth dongle can support aptx audio as a sink (input) ?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

This might sound strange but the setup is as follows. Raspberry Pi with very high quality sound card is a music centre. Tv/Projector with bluetooth and aptx support.

Maybe another way to put it would be, are there any bidirectional aptx dongles ?

Comment: Hi barrymac. Your question has been closed because it doesn't include enough detail for anyone to understand exactly what you're looking for. If you could edit your question to include detailed specifications, your question can be reopened. Thanks!

Comment: I think he's asking if a bluetooth dongle can support aptx. I am not sure my self. I have a headphone that support aptx. It seems that there is no latency when I uses that headphone with my bluetooth dongle. I have no idea if that bluetooth dongle support aptx or not.

Comment: I bought this https://www.tokopedia.com/snapshot.pl?dtl_id=52679614&order_id=34704194 and http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=282192 says that it supports aptx